# Map column of dataframe with different dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe df with two columns.

The 'data' column has some values, such as:

```
df['data'] = [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The 'Dict' column has multiple dictionary, such as:

```
df['Dict'] = [{0: ['IPM_0'], 1: ['IPM_1']},
              {0: ['SPM_0'], 1: ['SPM_1']},
              {0: ['NPM_0'], 1: ['NPM_1']},
              {0: ['DPM_0'], 1: ['DPM_1']}]
```

Now I want to map each 'data'with the relative dictionary in 'Dict', such as that the result looks like:

```
df['result'] = [IPM_0, SPM_1, NPM_0, DPM_1]
```

I tried to use `df['result'] = df.data.map(df.Dict)` but I get a column with the same values as in df.Dict.

I tried also `df['result'] = df.data.apply(lambda rows: rows.map(rows.Dict))` but I get an error  `'int' object has no attribute 'map'`

How can I achieve the result?

starting point:

```
   data                          Dict
0     0  {0: ['IPM_0'], 1: ['IPM_1']}
1     1  {0: ['SPM_0'], 1: ['SPM_1']}
2     0  {0: ['NPM_0'], 1: ['NPM_1']}
3     1  {0: ['DPM_0'], 1: ['DPM_1']}
```

ending point:

```
   data                          Dict result
0     0  {0: ['IPM_0'], 1: ['IPM_1']}  IPM_0
1     1  {0: ['SPM_0'], 1: ['SPM_1']}  SPM_1
2     0  {0: ['NPM_0'], 1: ['NPM_1']}  NPM_0
3     1  {0: ['DPM_0'], 1: ['DPM_1']}  DPM_1
```

Comment: kindly provide the source dataframe, with the expected output, as well as the mapping dictionary. ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: I just posted them on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are always handy:

```
df['result'] = [x[y][0] for x, y in zip(df['Dict'], df['data'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`. Keep in mind that storing complex structures in dataframes **is not efficient**!

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['Dict'][r['data']], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   data                          Dict   result
0     0  {0: ['IPM_0'], 1: ['IPM_1']}  [IPM_0]
1     1  {0: ['SPM_0'], 1: ['SPM_1']}  [SPM_1]
2     0  {0: ['NPM_0'], 1: ['NPM_1']}  [NPM_0]
3     1  {0: ['DPM_0'], 1: ['DPM_1']}  [DPM_1]
```

and if you want the first item of the list:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['Dict'][r['data']][0], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   data                          Dict result
0     0  {0: ['IPM_0'], 1: ['IPM_1']}  IPM_0
1     1  {0: ['SPM_0'], 1: ['SPM_1']}  SPM_1
2     0  {0: ['NPM_0'], 1: ['NPM_1']}  NPM_0
3     1  {0: ['DPM_0'], 1: ['DPM_1']}  DPM_1
```